# SSH Authentication order

Tags: ssh, sshd

I want to set the authentication order when a user wants to log in.

```
Match User user
    PasswordAuthentication no
    MaxAuthTries 5
    AuthenticationOrder "publickey,password"
Match all
    PasswordAuthentication yes
    AuthenticationMethods "publickey,password" "publickey,keyboard-interactive"
```

I want to set for ***user***, if he doesn't have publickey, then use the password. If he has publickey then logs in.

All user needs to have a publickey and a password to log in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try modifying the `Allow User user` section like so:

```
Match User user
    PasswordAuthentication yes
    MaxAuthTries 5
    AuthenticationMethods publickey password
```

When you list authentication methods as a comma-separated list the user must complete all of the listed methods. Listing the methods as a space-separated list will try each method until one is successful. So in my suggestion if `publickey` authentication is successful the user is given access, if it does not work it will ask for a password.

Also make sure to change the `PasswordAuthentication` bit to yes since you have to explicitly enable any authentication method listed.

Check out the sshd man page for more info: [OpenSSH sshd_config man page#AuthenticationMethods](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config.5#AuthenticationMethods)